# Assign the result of this transformation with map to a variable with autocasting

Tags: collections, kotlin, transformation

I am working with the next code:

```
private fun buildItemsList(navMenu: NavMenu?, appName: String): MutableList<Item> {
        val items: MutableList<Item> = arrayListOf()
        navMenu?.items?.map { item ->
            when (item) {
                is NavMenu -> items.add(buildMenuItem(item, appName))
                is NavLink -> items.add(buildItem(item, appName))
                else -> throw IllegalStateException("Unknown subtype ${item::class.simpleName} of NavMenu")
            }
        }
        return items
    }
```

Instead of adding to the item list, I should be able to assign the result to items. According to: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html

Something like:

```
val items = navMenu?.items?.map { }
```

I have some doubts about how to achieve this, because of, I am using autocasting (when). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
private fun buildItemsList(navMenu: NavMenu?, appName: String): List<Item> {
    if (navMenu == null || navMenu!!.items == null) {
        return emptyList()
    }
    return navMenu!!.items!!.map { item ->
            when (item) {
                is NavMenu -> buildMenuItem(item, appName)
                is NavLink -> buildItem(item, appName)
                else -> throw IllegalStateException("Unknown subtype ${item::class.simpleName} of NavMenu")
            }
        }
}
```

OR

```
private fun buildItemsList(navMenu: NavMenu?, appName: String): List<Item> {
    if (navMenu == null || navMenu!!.items == null) {
        return emptyList()
    }
    return navMenu!!.items!!.filter { it is NavMenu }.map { buildMenuItem(it as NavMenu, appName) } +
           navMenu!!.items!!.filter { it is NavLink }.map { buildItem(it as NavLink, appName) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have some doubts about how to achieve this, because of, I am using
>   autocasting.

Note: The fact that a type can be inferred from the context without explicitely specifying it is called [Smart Cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts) in Kotlin (not auto cast).

---

Given that `buildMenuItem` and `buildItem` return an `Item` you could do the following:

```
private fun buildItemsList(navMenu: NavMenu?, appName: String) = navMenu?.items?.map { item ->
    when (item) {
        is NavMenu -> buildMenuItem(item, appName)
        is NavLink -> buildItem(item, appName)
        else -> throw IllegalStateException("Unknown subtype ${item::class.simpleName} of NavMenu")
    }
} ?: emptyList()
```

The inferred return type will be `List<Item>`. If you need a mutable list add a `toMutableList()` call.

---

If you need to filter for the types separately using [`filterIsInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-is-instance.html) would be a good idea.

Usage:

```
val l = listOf(1, 2, "Hello").filterIsInstance<String>()
```

l will be of type `List<String>`.